# How do I stop comments of a exe script executing from a .bat fie

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a `.bat` file that runs a number of `.exe` scripts used recursively for a number of files and produces different result files.

But each `.exe` has some useless comments and processes running messages that pop up in my `cmd` window.

For example, a line in one of my scripts:

```
for %F in ("*.fa") do  "../program.exe" -input %F -output %~dpnF.fasta & copy %F + %~dpnF.fasta %dpnF.txt
```

When I run it, `program.exe` shows different comments and each ones' running information.

How can I stop those messages to pop up in my `cmd` prompt?

Comment: An example of the output would help. But for the most part you could just redirect stdout to nul.

Comment: isn't that also not suppress the output files? & if u mean applying '2> nul'.. I have already done that, it only stops the error  messages

Comment: It shouldn't as you are specifying an output file with your program. You should just be able to do this if you want to redirect stdout and stderr to nul. `"../program.exe" -input %F -output %~dpnF.fasta >nul 2>&1`

Comment: Remember if you are going to use this code from a batch file you need to double the percent symbols.

Comment: but it is still showing

Comment: If the program is writing directly to the console you cannot suppress the messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the messages of your batch file to a text file if you don't want to see them on cmd
For ex:

```
C:\\>run.bat > d:\myfile.txt
```

Comment: for %%F in ("*.fa") do  "../../Programs/dep/usearch/usearch.exe" -ublast %%F -db "../../Programs/database/database.fasta" -evalue 1e-5 -accel 0.5 -dbmatched %%~dpnF.fas & type %%F %%~dpnF.fas > %%~dpnF.fasta   2>nul

Comment: if I add >tempfile.txt after the exe script, the .fasta output is not generate,, and also it does not prevent the process running messages from pooping up

Comment: don't add the >tempfile.txt after the exe script. Set this redirect for the top  batch file which you run from cmd